# Why no smb.service GNOME file manager can still mount a disk from network?

Tags: networking, files, gnome, samba

Tested in Ubuntu 20.04

The smb service and smbd service didn't start.

I can still use GNOME file manager to discover network share folders, and I can mount it.

Comment: it's unclear, but are you saying smbd is not running on your Ubuntu 20.04 system, but you can still mount samba shares from that system? or are you mounting samba shares ON that system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smbd.service` is the basic service needed for making *your* computer share folders to others using the Windows-compatible SMB/CIFS protocol. But SMB/CIFS is not the only way to access network shares: the GNOME file manager supports several other protocols that could be used to share files over the network, such as:

- NFS
- WebDAV (with or without SSL/TLS security)
- FTP
- SSH (with its SFTP extension)

If the network share is provided using any of these other protocols, disabling `smbd.service` has no impact on it, neither in the server nor the client end.

I'm not actually sure what `smb.service` is; no such service exists in Debian, for example. But all that is needed to **mount** Windows-style network shares is in the Linux kernel, in the `cifs` network filesystem module. GNOME also has an user-space implementation of a SMB/CIFS client, in the form of [GVfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVfs) backend components.

To **discover** Windows-style network shares, you need just a client which supports the appropriate browsing protocol:

- In an Active Directory environment, network share discovery happens using DNS SRV records.
- In non-Active Directory environments, Windows systems that have already disabled the deprecated, insecure SMB protocol version 1 will support network share discovery using a protocol called [*WS-Discovery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery). Samba does not yet support this discovery protocol, but there are add-on services that can work alongside `smbd` to announce the shares to other computers using this protocol, like [wsdd](https://github.com/christgau/wsdd) and [wsdd2](https://github.com/Netgear/wsdd2); some Linux distributions already provide pre-packaged versions of those.
- If you don't have Active Directory and the deprecated, insecure SMBv1 is still active, network share discovery happens using old [NetBIOS over TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS_over_TCP/IP). On new Windows installations, this share discovery method is disabled server-side by default since year 2017; the client side will auto-disable itself if no SMBv1 servers are accessed during the first 15 days of uptime after installation. (I mention this to emphasize the fact that Microsoft **really, really wants this old, insecure protocol version to die soon** - and you should too.)

When using GNOME file manager to access Windows/SMB shares, the GNOME file manager is the browsing client, and GVfs is used to actually access the shares. No Samba services are needed at the client end at all.